# My google apps site become unstable after hosting company changed the nameserver

Tags: google-app-engine

Domain Name:www.wianga.com

I successfully configured the domain and  apps last month in google apps.yesterday the hosting company which has my domain DNS changed the name server.
After that site is up for some time and down for most of time..
,but I can assess all my app services.
TXT record verification is failing from web master tool.
I pinged www.wianga.com and its replying and showing Google servers.
But if i take the site in browser its showing  following error,
Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown error.
Please help me..i launched my site just 2 weeks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're having trouble with your nameservers. You need to contact your host and ask them to resolve it, or find a new host.

Comment: thanks ..my peoblem solved automatically.I dont know what happened but after a day it got solved and my site is up again.